# Identifying plot format

Tags: file-format, file-types

I have program writing unknown (for me) plot format. Please help identifying.

file.plo:

```
ax 16 16
xr 0 3500
yr 0 3500
tc 7 5 7 5
ra -12    6.    5. 0.1 0.1  0.963
dr
ra -12    9.    5. 0.1 0.1  0.219
dr
ra -12   18.    5. 0.1 0.1  0.143
dr
ra -12    6.    8. 0.1 0.1  0.175
dr
ra -12    9.    8. 0.1 0.1  0.862
dr
ra -12    9.    8. 0.1 0.1  0.318
[... and so on...]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an [HP Graphics Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HPGL) plotter file.

In the future, you might try googling ".*extension* format" or ".*extension* file". 99% of the time, you'll find the file format in the very first result.

There are plenty of FOSS HPGL and HPGL/2 interpreters and convertors:

- [HPGS](http://hpgs.berlios.de)
- [HPGL Viewer](http://hpglviewer.com/)
- [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/)
- [hp2xx](http://www.gnu.org/software/hp2xx/hp2xx.html)
- [PStoEdit](http://www.pstoedit.net/pstoedit)
- [KVEC](http://freecode.com/projects/kvec)
- [google.com/search?q=open+source+HPGL](http://google.com/search?q=open%20source%20HPGL)

In addition to these, a lot of CAD and vector graphics programs support HPGL. Though there seems to be a lack of standardization in file extensions used, including: .hpgl, .hpg, .hgl, .plt, .hp, etc.

Also, later versions of [PCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printer_Command_Language) seems to support HPGL as well, so this further adds to the hardware and software support for the format.

More info can be found [here](http://www.hp9845.net/9845/projects/9111/).

*Edit: Thank you G Koe for initially appending my comment to this answer and prompting me to make a little more effort to expand it. I've community wikied this answer so other **freeware** and **open source** apps may be added, as I'm sure HPGL's support is more extensive than what's currently listed.*